# Ошибка only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, не могу разобраться, как исправить

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import math
t1 = 600
t2 = 3600
t3 = 18000
t4 = 36000
t5 = 72000
T = 924
C0 = 0.024
Cs = 1.4
D = 9.79e-14
x = np.arange(0.0, 0.13, 0.1)
def a(x, t, D, Cs, C0):
    return ((Cs - C0)*math.erfc(((x*0.01)*0.01)/(2*((D*t)**0.5))) + C0)*100
C1 = a(x,t1,D,Cs,C0) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,C1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Функция `math.erfc()` ожидает число на входе. А вы ей `numpy.ndarray` скормили (потому как `x` такой).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать векторизированный аналог скалярной функции `math.erfc` - [scipy.special.erfc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfc.html), которая умеет работать с векторами:

```
from scipy.special import erfc

def a(x, t, D, Cs, C0):
    return ((Cs - C0)*erfc(((x*0.01)*0.01)/(2*((D*t)**0.5))) + C0)*100
C1 = a(x,t1,D,Cs,C0) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,C1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS ваш вектор `x` состоит всего из двух элементов, поэтому и график такой...

```
In [161]: x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 200)

In [162]: C1 = a(x,t1,D,Cs,C0)
     ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     ...: ax.plot(x,C1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, прям выручили, все работает! Когда я работаю с erfc всегда нужно использовать векторизированный аналог скалярной функции?

Comment: @Даня, если вы передаете функции нескалярное значение - список/вектор/матрицу, то такая функция должна быть готова к таким аргументам. Большинство функций и методов в модулях Numpy, SciPy, Pandas умеют работать с нескалярными значениями